# Performance tuning in querying multiple databases in a Spring boot microservice

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, spring-data-jpa, spring-webflux

I have a service written in Spring boot and uses Spring Data JPA to retrieve data from 8 different Oracle DBs. All the DBs have same schema and the query is the same as well. Current implementation  is not performing very well since the queries are getting executed sequentially and the response takes many minutes.

Currently I use multitenancy in Spring data JPA with different Datasource and Entitymanager configurations and iterate through them to achieve this. Will creating a multi-threaded architecture improve the performance or is there any other framework or design patterns which can help with this. I haven't worked on Spring Webflux, but would implementing that help with the performance ?

Comment: You are describing at a high level a complex implementation. It is very difficult that someone can give you anything but generic suggestions that you will need to test in your environment with your use cases and data. Stackoverlow is intended for more specific questions.

Comment: The answer is definitely "Yes", but it's hard to provide a more detailed answer

Comment: I think this is typically the case where Webflux + R2DBC / ReactiveRepositories would shine, because the streaming + non-blocking aspect should allow to return data parts little by little, and Reactor operators should allow to merge each db response efficiently and seemlessly. But, as already said by other comments, your question is too broad to provide a good and detailed answer.

Answer (score 1):

I would recommend looking into the following topics:

- **Fetch Size:** (by default its 10) if you need to fetch hundreds or thousands of entries, this can dramatically improve performance by reducing the network calls between the database and application. This is especially critical if the database are not in the same network or further away, goes through VPN, etc.
- **Connection pool min, max, idle size:** depending on the concurrency of your application, this might dramatically help as well setting it properly.
- **Setting read only flag:** By default for hibernate it is read and write mode. You can speed up and save some memory as well if you tell the query that it is for read only.
- **Multithreading:** Yes you are right, you can utilize multithreading, I would recommend creating an ExecutorService and submitting the tasks, then waiting until the slowest, as well as the rest completed. Since from application point of view querying the data is mostly waiting, as the database does the majority of the work.

Generally hard to give an exact answer how to do it right, since it depends on many factors, but if you start learning more about these topics can go far way.

Very good materials to start with:

- https://vladmihalcea.com/hibernate-performance-tuning-tips
- https://vladmihalcea.com/the-anatomy-of-connection-pooling
- https://vladmihalcea.com/spring-read-only-transaction-hibernate-optimization
- https://www.baeldung.com/java-executor-service-tutorial

Good luck with the optimization!